# Find the list of rows which contains only one value in the field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column which has some of the fields like this ['CULLIPHER', 'JONES'], ['PEELER', 'PEELER'], ['SEWARD'] and I want to find the list of fields which contain only one value in the field e.g ['SEWARD'] in pandas

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: `df.loc[df['my_col'].str.len().eq(1), 'my_col'].values.tolist()`?